# Howto configure jks certificate in webservice client in websphere 5

Tags: web-services, ssl, client, websphere, jks

I followed different guide in internet googling without solution.
I have in backend layer configured proxy for the stub and for stub endpoint https URL.
Using SoapUI and same jks file and proxy all work fine.
In websphere go out remote exception that address not exists...
Somebody can help me to configure step by step jks and call webService method in SSL?

THKS

Comment: How I setted jks in websphere 5.1:

I opened server configuration in Security Tab I setted in SSL configuration Repertoires a new alias: localhost/WS_Client
In Key file I inserted full path of jks file
In Password I setted password
In format selected JKS value

Then I opened webservices.xml and in Port Binding Tab of window in HTTP SSL Configuration I inserted localhost/WS_Client.

Comment: In java class where I create stub setted proxy server to go out of intranet with follow methods:
((Stub)service)._setProperty("cachedhttpProxyHost","proxy host server");
((Stub)service)._setProperty("cachedhttpProxyPort","proxy port server");
((Stub)service)._setProperty("cachedhttpProxyUser","username for proxy server");
((Stub)service)._setProperty("cachedhttpProxyPassword","password for proxy server");
logger.info("Setted on stub proxy configuration.");

I commented value in previous code for proxy server.

Somebody can help to solve this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Open file jre/lib/security/java.security of runtime directory and set correct provider:

security.provider.1=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2

The you can use as provider IBMJSSE2 and all work fine.